# Angular2 Material Design Select Component - Styling selected Item

Tags: angular, angular-material2, md-select

I'm using the `<md-select>`component of [Angular2 Material](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview) to switch list layouts (grid or bullet list). 
When a layout has been chosen, the select-box should only show an icon. When choosing a layout the menu is showing both the icon and text.

Here's what it should look like

[image: select icon without text]

this is what the selection menu looks like:

[image]

my code so far:

```
<md-select [(ngModel)]="selectedViewState">
    <md-option *ngFor="let viewState of viewStates" [value]="viewState.icon">
        <i class="mdi {{viewState.icon}}"></i> {{viewState.title}}
    </md-option>
</md-select>
```

So, how can I style this? I didn't find anything regarding this in the docs.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/1273